# User.Identity.Name.ToString() returns blank

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have converted a Visual Studio 2008 project to Visual Studio 2013.  The only problem I can see is with the following line:

```
UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

After this line is run; UserName is always a blank string even though I am signed in.  I have loaded the Visual Studio 2008 project and it works ok.  The web.config in the 2013 project is identical and has the following line set (recommended in other posts):

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Why does User.Identity.Name.ToString() return a blank string in Visual Studio 2013?

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns TRUE in Visual Studio 2008 and FALSE in Visual Studio 2013 (on same development PC).

Comment: Is it a web application or website? Is is hosted on IIS Server or asp.net Development server?

Comment: @Thanos Markou, it is a web application.  I assume it is hosted on a development server, but I am not sure? Could this be the problem?